# How to convert a date and time to be stored in mysql datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-formatting

How do I convert this to be stored in mysql database with a datetime field?

```
$phptime = '02/21/2014 9:30 am';
```

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your question, but I think you will find it better in the long run to save your dates as unix timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to a timestamp, then use the php date function to get it in the format you want.

```
$datetimeString = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $phptime ) );
```

Comment: If the string is always going to be in the same format you can use DateTime as in @John's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to read in and format the date.

```
$phptime = '02/21/2014 9:30 am';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i a', $phptime);
$mysqltime = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

***MySQL*** solution: Use `STR_TO_DATE` function with the php datetime value as input.

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '02/21/2014 9:30 am', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p' ) dt;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 2014-02-21 09:30:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Refer to***:

- [**MySQL: STR_TO_DATE(str,format) Function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I had the experience that you have to separate the components and rearrange them to the mysql datetime format. I have done this before posting it to php and [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) it in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

So like this:

```
strtotime($phptime);
```